# Bootstrap Thumbnail Image Spacing

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a strange issue. For some reason my images inside my thumbnails are not "filling" the thumbnail image section. There is a good bit of spacing between the thumbnail border then the image.[image: Problem]

I am trying to remove the white space you see around the iamges. I have already tried `width: 100%`

```
 .thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
}

    .thumbnail {
    box-shadow: 0 0 23px black;
}
```

I want the img to go all the way to edge of the thumbnail

HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="row hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                            <img src="../images/Signs/SignsFrontPageBanner.gif" class="img-rounded  header" style="max-width: 100%; ">
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">

                            <h1 id="featured">Sign Templates</h1>

                            <div col="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">
                                    <a href="http://inksigns.com/InkSigns/index.html" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default active">Signs</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                                <div class="thumbnail backgroundhover">
                                    <a href="RealEstateSigns/RealEstateSign-index.html"><img src="../images/RealEstate/RealEstateSignThumbnail.gif" class="img-rounded"></a>
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <h4 class="pull-right"></h4>
                                        <h4 style="text-align: center;"><a href="RealEstateSigns/RealEstateSign-index.html">Real Estate</a>
                            </h4>
                                        <p>Take a look at our wide assortment of Real Estate Signs & Accessories.</p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                                <div class="thumbnail backgroundhover">
                                    <a href="../Banners/GeneralBanners.html"><img src="../images/Banners/BannerThumbnail.gif" class="img-rounded "></a>
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <h4 class="pull-right"></h4>
                                        <h4 style="text-align: center;"><a href="../Banners/GeneralBanners.html">Banners</a>
                            </h4>
                                        <p>Take a look at our wide assortment of Banners.</p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                                <div class="thumbnail backgroundhover">
                                    <a href="../Magnets/magnets-index.html"><img src="../images/Magnets/FrontPageMagnetThumbnail.gif" class="img-rounded "></a>
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <h4 class="pull-right"></h4>
                                        <h4 style="text-align: center;"><a href="../Magnets/magnets-index.html">Magnets</a>
                            </h4>
                                        <p>Take a look at our wide assortment of magnets.</p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                                <div class="thumbnail backgroundhover">
                                    <a href="Decals/DecalSigns-index.html"><img src="../images/Decals/DecalsThumbnail.gif" alt="" class="img-rounded "></a>
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <h4 class="pull-right"></h4>
                                        <h4 style="text-align: center;"><a href="Decals/DecalSigns-index.html">Decals</a>
                            </h4>
                                        <p>Take a look at our wide assortment of Decals.</p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Either your images or the divs that contain the images have padding.

You should try setting the thumbnails to **padding:0;**  --  if that fails, try it on the containing divs. Post the jfiddle if neither of those works and I'll find it for you.

Comment: If i added padding:0 to background hover it will resize the img and remove the padding. But when i add padding: 0 to the thumbnail class nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding `padding: 0px !important;` to .thumbnail, it need the !important